# Connecting Python with Teradata using Teradata module

Tags: python, connection, odbc, teradata

I have installed python 2.7.0 and Teradata module on Windows 7. I am not able to connect and query TD from python.

`pip install Teradata`

Now I want to import teradata module in my source code and perform operations like -

1. Firing queries to teradata and get result set.
2. Check if connection is made to teradata.

Please help me writing code for the same as I am new to Python and there is no information available with me to connect to teradata.

Comment: There is information here https://developer.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module - You will also need the Teradata ODBC drivers http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/odbc-driver/windows

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are a number of ways to connect to Teradata and export table to Pandas. Here are four+:

### [Using teradata module](https://github.com/Teradata/PyTd)

```
# You can install teradata via PIP: pip install teradata
# to get a list of your odbc drivers names, you could do: teradata.tdodbc.drivers
# You don’t need to install teradata odbc driver if using method='rest'.     
# See sending data from df to teradata for connection example 

import teradata
import pandas as pd

host,username,password = 'HOST','UID', 'PWD'
#Make a connection
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=False)


with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=host, username=username,
                            password=password, driver="DRIVERNAME") as connect:

    query = "SELECT * FROM DATABASEX.TABLENAMEX;"

    #Reading query to df
    df = pd.read_sql(query,connect)
    # do something with df,e.g.
    print(df.head()) #to see the first 5 rows
```

### [Using TeradataSQL](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/#description)

> from @ymzkala : This package doesn't require you to install Teradata drivers (other than this package).

```
# Installing python -m pip install teradatasql

import teradatasql

with teradatasql.connect(host='host', user='username', password='password') as connect:
    df = pd.read_sql(query, connect)
```

### [Using pyodbc module](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc)

```
import pyodbc

 #You can install teradata via PIP: pip install pyodbc
 #to get a list of your odbc drivers names, you could do: pyodbc.drivers()

#Make a connection
link = 'DRIVER={DRIVERNAME};DBCNAME={hostname};UID={uid};PWD={pwd}'.format(
                      DRIVERNAME=DRIVERNAME,hostname=hostname,  
                      uid=username, pwd=password)
with pyodbc.connect(link,autocommit=True) as connect:

    #Reading query to df
    df = pd.read_sql(query,connect)
```

### Using [sqlalchemy Module](https://github.com/Teradata/sqlalchemy-teradata)

```
 #You can install sqlalchemy via PIP: pip install sqlalchemy-teradata
 #Note: It is not pip install sqlalchemy. If you already have sqlalchemy, you still need sqlalchemy-teradata to get teradata dialects

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#Make a connection

link = 'teradata://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/?driver={DRIVERNAME}'.format(
               username=username,hostname=hostname,DRIVERNAME=DRIVERNAME)

with create_engine(link) as connect:

    #Reading query to df
    df = pd.read_sql(query,connect)
```

There is a fifth way, using [giraffez module](https://github.com/capitalone/giraffez). I enjoy using this module as it come with MLOAD, FASTLOAD, BULKEXPORT etc. The only issue for beginners is its requirements (e.g C/C++ compiler ,Teradata CLIv2 and TPT API headers/lib files).

Note: Updated 13-07-2018, using of context manager to ensure closing of sessions

**Update: 31-10-2018: Using teradata to send data from df to teradata**

We can send data from df to Teradata. Avoiding 'odbc' 1 MB limit and odbc driver dependency, we can use 'rest' method. We need host ip_address, instead of driver argument. **NB:** The order of columns in df should match the order of columns in Teradata table.

```
import teradata
import pandas as pd

# HOST_IP can be found by executing *>>nslookup viewpoint* or *ping  viewpoint* 
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=False) 
with udaExec.connect(method="rest",system="DBName", username="UserName",
                      password="Password", host="HOST_IP_ADDRESS") as connect:

    data = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_records(index=False)]

    connect.executemany("INSERT INTO DATABASE.TABLEWITH5COL values(?,?,?,?,?)",data,batch=True)
```

Using 'odbc', you have to chunk your data to less than 1MB chunks to avoid "[HY001][Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Memory allocation error" error: E.g.

```
import teradata
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=False)

with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system="DBName", username="UserName",
                      password="Password", driver="DriverName") as connect:

    #We can divide our huge_df to small chuncks. E.g. 100 churchs
    chunks_df = np.array_split(huge_df, 100)

    #Import chuncks to Teradata
    for i,_ in enumerate(chunks_df):

        data = [tuple(x) for x in chuncks_df[i].to_records(index=False)]
        connect.executemany("INSERT INTO DATABASE.TABLEWITH5COL values(?,?,?,?,?)",data,batch=True)
```

Comment: teradata.api.DatabaseError: (0, '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Loading the Teradata ICU Library Failed. Error is: 126, The driver returned invalid (or failed to return) SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER: 03.80')

Comment: When you print(teradata.tdodbc.drivers), can you see the correct driver name? My initial thought is that you might have install/update your teradata odbc driver and need to explicitly assign driver a correct name as default ‘teradata’ does not match.

Comment: Note: The best way is to use ‘with’ syntax .This will ensure closing of sessions.

Comment: I tried print(teradata.tdodbc.drivers), I got None. But I am still connecting using Pyodbc. I have issues with Sqlalchemy as NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata. I'm trying to write a df to Teradata.

Comment: I enjoy using teradata packages as it is maintained by teradata. I get df to teradata question a lot so I will edit my answer above

Comment: @PraysonDaniel, Thanks for your reply. I created a sample df with 5 rows and 35 columns. I got the below error, but still it loads the 5 rows to Teradata table. Any ideas? ERROR:teradata.udaexec:Query Failed! Duration: 0.200 seconds, Query: INSERT INTO db.table values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 DatabaseError: (0, u'[HY024] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid argument value')

Comment: What do you mean by rest method?

Comment: You are using a wrong driver. You need Teradata driver and not Microsoft. You can either down teradata odbc driver and use that or change method from 'odbc' to 'rest' and use Teradata RestAPI

Comment: using Using teradata module its showing "(434, '[HY000] [Teradata][WSock32 DLL] (434) WSA E TimedOut: No response received when attempting to connect to the Teradata server')" . any idea hoe to resolve this??

Comment: I had to add the following
```
import teradata
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=False) 
with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system="servername", username="****",password="****",driver="Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20",authentication="LDAP") as connect:
    data =pd.read_sql('select top 10 * from DBName.Table,connect)
```

Answer (score 11):

To add on to [Prayson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46538793/2740563) answer, you can use the teradatasql package ([found on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/)). This package doesn't require you to install Teradata drivers (other than this package). Use it like so:

```
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd

with teradatasql.connect(host='host', user='username', password='password') as connect:
    data = pd.read_sql('select top 5 * from table_name;', connect)
```

Answer (score 4):

Download the Teradata Python module and python pyodbc.pyd from internet.
Install using cmd install setup.py.

Here is the sample script for connecting to teradata and extracting data:

```
import teradata
import pyodbc
import sys



udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0",
        logConsole=False)

session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", dsn="prod32",
        username="PRODRUN", password="PRODRUN");

i = 0
REJECTED = 'R';

f = file("output.txt","w");sys.stdout=f

cursor =  session.cursor();

ff_remaining = 0;

cnt = cursor.execute("SELECT  SEQ_NO,FRQFBKDC,PNR_RELOC FROM ttemp.ffremaining ORDER BY 1,2,3 ").rowcount;
rows = cursor.execute("SELECT  SEQ_NO,FRQFBKDC,PNR_RELOC FROM ttemp.ffremaining ORDER BY 1,2,3 ").fetchall();


for i in range(cnt):
    ff_remaining = cursor.execute("select count(*) as coun from  ttemp.ffretroq_paxoff where seq_no=? and status <> ?",(rows[i].seq_no,REJECTED)).fetchall();
    print ff_remaining[0].coun, rows[i].seq_no, REJECTED;
```

Comment: session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", dsn="prod32",driver=DriverName,username="PRODRUN", password="PRODRUN");
We also need to pass driver as a parameter while creating a session.

Comment: getting below error

teradata.api.DatabaseError: (0, '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Loading the Teradata ICU Library Failed. Error is: 126, The driver returned invalid (or failed to return) SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER: 03.80')

Comment: Is there a reason to use both teradata and pyodbc. ;)?

Answer (score 1):

Please find my solution for below.
(For Authentication mechanism: Password Protected)

```
    import teradatasql
    DB_URL = ""                                 #Add Host
    USER = ""                                   #Add Username
    PASS = ""                                   #Add Password
    try:
        # Establish a connection to the Teradata database
        with teradatasql.connect(host=DB_URL, user=USER, password=PASS) as con:
            # Create a cursor to execute queries
            with con.cursor() as cur:
                try:
                    
                    cur.execute(f"select top 10 * from user.TEST")
     
                    # Extract data from the result set and print it
                    for row in cur:
                        print(f"Associate ID: {row[0]}")
                except teradatasql.DatabaseError as db_err:
                    # Handle any errors that occur during query execution
                    print("Error while executing the query:", db_err)
    except teradatasql.DatabaseError as db_err:
        # Handle any errors that occur during the database connection
        print("Error while connecting to the Teradata database:", db_err)
    for Authentication mechanism : LDAP
import teradata

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="MyApp", version="1.0", logConsole=True)

session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="", username="", password="", authentication="LDAP")

var="select top 10 * from user.TEST"

for row in session.execute(var):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).