# Connecting to Teradata using Python

Tags: python, teradata, pandas-to-sql

I am trying to connect to teradata server and load a dataframe into a table using python. Here is my code -

```
import sqlalchemy 

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("teradata://username:passwor@hostname:port/")

f3.to_sql(con=engine, name='sample', if_exists='replace', schema = 'schema_name')
```

But I am getting the following error -

```
InterfaceError: (teradata.api.InterfaceError) ('DRIVER_NOT_FOUND', "No driver found for 'Teradata'.  Available drivers: SQL Server,SQL Server Native Client 11.0,ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server")
```

Can anybody help me to figure out whats wrong in my approach?

Comment: Check out https://developer.teradata.com/tools/articles/teradata-sqlalchemy-introduction

Answer (score 3):

There's is different ways to connect to Teradata in Python. The following list is not exhaustive.

**SQLAlchemy**

If you wish to use [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), you will also need to install the package [SQLAlchemy-Teradata](https://github.com/Teradata/sqlalchemy-teradata). Here is how you can connect:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, DeferredReflection
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

[...]

# Connect
engine = create_engine('teradata://' + user + ':' + password + '@' + host + ':22/' + database)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
db_session.execute('SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;')  # To avoid locking tables when doing select on tables
db_session.commit()

Base = declarative_base(cls=DeferredReflection)
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

Then you can use `db_session` to make queries. See [SQLAlchemy Session API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html)

**Pyodbc**

If you wish to use [Pyodbc](https://developer.teradata.com/blog/odbcteam/2016/02/python-with-teradata-odbc) you will first need to install Teradata driver on your machine. Example on mine, after installing Teradata driver I have the following entry in `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[Teradata]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/16.00/odbc_64/lib/tdata.so
APILevel=CORE
ConnectFunctions=YYY
DriverODBCVer=3.51
SQLLevel=1
```

Then I can connect with the following:

```
import pyodbc
[...]

#Teradata Connection
connection= pyodbc.connect("driver={Teradata};dbcname=" + host + ";uid=" + user + ";pwd=" + pwd + ";charset=utf8;", autocommit=True)
connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-8')
connection.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')

cursor= n.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select 'Hello World'")
for row in cursor:
    print (row)
```

Comment: what kind of driver SQLAlchemy is using? also odbc?

Comment: I don’t know exactly what’s the underlying techno used by SQLAlchemy but I don’t think is uses ODBC protocol

Comment: It’s using DB-API protocol https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/

Answer (score 1):

To connect to a teradata database, you need pyodbc, i also have problems with teradata dialect.

Example:

```
import pyodbc

user = 'user'

pasw = 'pass'

host = 'host'

connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=Teradata;DBCNAME=' + host +';UID=' + user + ';PWD=' + pasw +';QUIETMODE=YES', autocommit=True,unicode_results=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your are using sqlalchemy. But you could explore using Teradata module to connect to Teradata as explained in the other link:
[Connecting Python with Teradata using Teradata module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938320/connecting-python-with-teradata-using-teradata-module)

Comment: I wanted to use the 'to_sql' feature of pandas' dataframe. Hence I used sqlalchemy. The problem was on index of the data frame. The issue is now solved when I use the following code;

f3.to_sql(con=engine, name='sample', if_exists='replace', schema = 'schema_name', index = False)

Comment: I'm getting the below error for teradata. Any ideas how to solve it? I'm using Anaconda. I can read from Teradata using Pyodbc. I can read/write from Oracle using sqlalchemy. I'm trying to write to Teradata, but no luck yet.

NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata

Comment: Do you have sqlalchemy module installed?

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar problem in airflow, I used jars and jaydebeapi to connect teradata database and execute sql:

```
[root@myhost transfer]# cat test_conn.py 
import jaydebeapi
from contextlib import closing


jclassname='com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'
jdbc_driver_loc = '/opt/spark-2.3.1/jars/terajdbc4-16.20.00.06.jar,/opt/spark-2.3.1/jars/tdgssconfig-16.20.00.06.jar'
jdbc_driver_name = 'com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'
host='my_teradata.address'

url='jdbc:teradata://' + host + '/TMODE=TERA'
login="teradata_user_name"
psw="teradata_passwd"

sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  A_TERADATA_TABLE_NAME where month_key='202009'"


conn = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=jdbc_driver_name,
                                  url=url, 
                                  driver_args=[login, psw],
                                  jars=jdbc_driver_loc.split(","))

with closing(conn) as conn:
    with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
        cur.execute(sql)
        print(cur.fetchall())
   
[root@myhost transfer]# python test_conn.py
[(7734133,)]
[root@myhost transfer]#
```