# Is there a way to store pandas dataframe to a Teradata table

Tags: python, dataframe, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have created a pandas data-frame 'df' and I am trying to store it in a 'table' using Teradata-SQL assistant.

Connection string -

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
         "DRIVER=Teradata;DBCNAME=tdprod;Authentication=LDAP;UID=" + username + ";PWD=" + password + ";QUIETMODE=YES",
        autocommit=True, unicode_results=True)

cursor = conn.cursor().execute(sql)
```

Tried using:  `df.to_sql('table', con =conn)`

This doesn't work.

Is there an easier way to store a dataframe into a table.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2158, in _wrap_pool_connect
return fn()
 File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 410, in connect
return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self, self._threadconns)
 File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 788, in _checkout
fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 529, in checkout
rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1096, in _do_get
c = self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 347, in _create_connection
return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 474, in __init__
self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
 File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 671, in __connect
connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
 File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 106, in connect
 return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
 File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 412, in connect
return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\teradata\tdodbc.py", line 454, in __init__
checkStatus(rc, hDbc=self.hDbc, method="SQLDriverConnectW")
 File "C:\Users\tripata\PycharmProjects\NLP\venv\lib\site-packages\teradata\tdodbc.py", line 231, in checkStatus
raise DatabaseError(i[2], u"[{}] {}".format(i[0], msg), i[0])
teradata.api.DatabaseError: (8017, '[28000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] The UserId, Password or Account is invalid. , [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] The UserId, Password or Account is invalid. ')
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for `to_sql`:

> ```
> Parameters
> ----------
> name : string
>     Name of SQL table.
> con : sqlalchemy.engine.Engine or sqlite3.Connection
>     Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that
>     library. Legacy support is provided for sqlite3.Connection objects.
> ```

You can see you need sqlalchemy *or* sqlite3, but not pyodbc.

You need the following to create an engine for Teradata:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(f'teradata://{username}:{password}@tdprod:22/')
```

You would then use it like

```
df.to_sql('table', engine)
```

Comment: Solution doesnt seem to run. It throws an error message - sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) . For some reason, it says UserId, Password, or Account invalid. I cross checked my account and it works fine.

Comment: Could you update the question with the full stack trace? It's hard to debug with only the error name.

Comment: Looks like the username or password is wrong. Just play with the  sqlalchemy connect string until it works.

Comment: So, I played around a bit and this seems to be working-                            
 create_engine('teradata://' +user+':'+ password + '@'+host+':1025/'+'/'+'?authentication=LDAP'). l guess we need both the host name and authentication  in the connection string.

Comment: How do you add the datalab and table name together using df.to_sql?

Answer (score 1):

I've done some digging and this solution does the job and does it quickly - using the python teradata module:

```
import teradata
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


num_of_chunks = 100  #breaking the data into chunks is optional - use if you have many rows or would like to view status updates

query = 'insert into SomeDB.SomeTeraDataTable'
df = someDataframe

#set host, user, password params
host,username,password = 'hostName_or_IPaddress','username', 'password'

#connet to DB using UdaExec
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="IMC", version="1.0", logConsole=False)


with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=host, username=username,
                            password=password, driver="Teradata") as connect:


    df_chunks = np.array_split(df, num_of_chunks)

    for i,_ in enumerate(df_chunks):

        data = [tuple(x) for x in df_chunks[i].to_records(index=False)]

        connect.executemany(query, data,batch=True)
```

solution based on: this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938320/connecting-python-with-teradata-using-teradata-module)

Answer (score 0):

```
create_engine('teradata://' +user+':'+ password + '@'+host+':1025/'+'/'+'?authentication=LDAP')
```

Adding both the host name and authentication to the connection string worked for me.